# json post nested objects in swift using alamofire

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

i want to post nested json objects in API using Alamofire my objects structere is like this

```
["example" :
 {
 "fname":"john",
 "lnamed":"Doe"
 },{
 "fname":"john",
 "lname":"Doe"
 },
.
.
.
]
```

my problem is when i'm making array it becomes like ["example":**[**["fname":"john","lname":"Doe"],["fname":"john","lname":"Doe"]**]**]
so their is one square bracket extra because of the array. below is my codes

```
var exampleObj = [String:AnyObject]()

var examplesArray  = [exampleObj]

    for example in examples
    {

        exampleObj = ["fname":example[fname] as AnyObject, "lname":example["lname"] as AnyObject]

        examplesArray.append(exampleObj)
    }



        let parameters = ["example": examplesArray]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after while i discovered my problem was with the Alamofire request i forgot to add the encoding parameter and the solution is

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
```