# Swift 3 : Alamofire POST request parameters issue

Tags: ios, swift, post, parameters, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire for using POST request. But I can't fill the `OrderDetails` items in `parameters` as you can see the code below. I post everything except  `OrderDetails` items. Can you see what is the problem?

I put this code in `for in` loop.

```
 let parameters: Parameters = ["UserId": 1,
                                              "CompanyId":id,
                                              "TableNumber":tableNumber ,
                                              "Description":all.details!,
                                              "OrderDetails": [
                                                "MenuItemId":Int(all.menuID!)!,
                                                "Piece":all.count!,
                                                "Description":all.customerDetails!
                    ]
                ]
```

Comment: check my previous answer with this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484772/how-to-post-nested-json-by-swiftyjson-and-alamofire/44500753#44500753 hope this helps

Comment: I see big problem with force unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on your swift,

```
let parameters: [String:Any] = ["UserId": 1,
                                  "CompanyId":1,
                                  "TableNumber":2 ,
                                  "Description":3,
                                  "OrderDetails": "{'MenuItemId':4,'Piece':5,'Description':2}"
]
```

and handle post data like this;

```
$OrderDetails = json_decode($_POST['OrderDetails'],true);
```

now you can, get your values from `$OrderDetails`

Comment: it didn't work. I still get null value in OrderDetails

Comment: Your null value is in server side?

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work neither. I put this code in "for in" loop. I get everything except orderdetails. I don't get it.

Comment: how handle post data on server side? please edit your question and ask clearly. Anyone will not help to you with this question. I am sorry