# Cannot convert return expression of type Promise (_,_) -> DataRequest to return type Promise<DataResponse,AnyObject>>

Tags: ios, swift3, promise, promisekit

Cannot convert return expression of type Promise (*,*) -> DataRequest to return type Promise>

my function is

```
func postJson(_ url: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> Promise<DataResponse<AnyObject>> {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

        return Promise { fulfill, reject in

        manager.request(request)
            .responseJSON { response in
                fulfill(response)
        }
```

And I get this error on the return Promise line. How do I convert ?

I tried changing my return signature to `Promise<DataRequest, Error` and get a compile error on that line that Promise is too specialized with 2 parameters instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `fulfill` because it's expecting parameter `DataResponse<AnyObject>` but you are passing `DataResponse<Any>`.

Changing return type of your `postJson` method to `Promise<DataResponse<Any>>` should solve your problem.

Change this line

```
func postJson(_ url: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> Promise<DataResponse<AnyObject>> {
```

to

```
func postJson(_ url: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> Promise<DataResponse<Any>> {
```