# Alamofire: syntax for writing a POST request with url, method, parameters, headers and encoding

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've had a look at tons of previous answers, but couldn't find an up-to-date one that includes ALL the following parameters: url, method, parameters, encoding, headers.

This:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { ... }
```

Gives the error: Extra argument "method" in call

---

**UPDATE 26/06/2017**

The format of the request is actually correct, the issue is that the format of one parameter sent was incorrect. The error is pretty misleading. See my answer below for a list of the parameter's types required and their default value.

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484772/how-to-post-nested-json-by-swiftyjson-and-alamofire/44500753#44500753 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639529/using-manager-request-with-post/44639768#44639768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cristallo's answer is a great custom way to do it.

In the meantime, I've discovered that the request in my original question actually works, at the condition that the value passed to the parameter headers is of type [String: String].

Alamofire's error is a bit misleading:

```
Extra argument 'method' in call.
```

Here is therefore the request that can be used:

```
Alamofire.request(
        url,
        method: .post,
        parameters: params,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: httpHeaders).responseJSON { response in
        ...
    }
```

With the parameters types expected and their default values (taken from Alamofire source code):

```
Alamofire.request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to create a specific request and then customize it using Request methods and properties

```
var request = URLRequest(url: yourUrl)
request.httpMethod = yourMethod 
request.setValue(yourCustomizedValue)
request.httpBody = yourBody
...

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {...}
```

Comment: Thanks cristallo, that helped a lot. It actually looks like the request in my question was actually correct. See answer below.

Comment: how would you add parameters to this example?