# Setting content-type header to use JSON with Swift 3 + AlamoFire

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

The answers in [Alamofire Swift 3.0 Extra parameter in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-parameter-in-call) did not work for me.

Setting header to `nil` compiles but I need `["Content-Type", "application/json"]`. Here I get an error of an extra parameter in th emethod

How do I take

`manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
            response in
                fulfill(response)
            }
        }`

and send JSON content-type?

The documentation shows

```
Automatic Validation

Automatically validates status code within 200..<300 range, and that the Content-Type header of the response matches the Accept header of the request, if one is provided.

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("Validation Successful")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I'm using `.responseJSON` but I'm not getting JSON back. So I think I need to send the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, there is another method overload that allow pass a dictionary with headers

```
    let request = Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: ["Content-Type" :"application/json"]).responseData { (response) in
        /***YOUR CODE***/
    }
```

for post JSON data in request check this answer [Using manager.request with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639529/using-manager-request-with-post/44639768#44639768)

Hope this helps you

Comment: @quantumpotato this answer helps your? did you solve your problem?