# Construct a JSON payload with list of strings in swift

Tags: json, swift

I would construct the below payload dynamically for a POST service call. I am not sure how to create a list of strings in dictionary

```
{
    "Id":"2025",
    "deviceType": "iphone",
    "category": ["Dental", "Vision"] 
}
```

My code

```
var categoryList = ["Dental", "Vision"]
let json = ["Id": "2025", "deviceType": "iphone", "category": categoryList] as! Dictionary<String, String>     
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

Comment: check this answer maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484772/how-to-post-nested-json-by-swiftyjson-and-alamofire/44500753#44500753

Comment: Change `as! Dictionary<String, String>` to `as [String: Any]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:-

and no need to onvert json into data you can directly post this json in SERVICE CAll as a parameter

```
let jsonToSend:[String:Any] = [
    "Id":"pass your id here",
    "deviceType":"device type here",
    "category":"category array here"
]
```