# response.result.value in alamofire post method is nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

```
        let parametersDictionary = [
        "email" : "name@gmail.com",
        "password" : "password"
    ]
    Alamofire.request("http://nanosoftech.com/store/user_check", method: .post, parameters: (parametersDictionary as NSDictionary) as? Parameters , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        print("response:", response.result.value)
    }
```

**I'm working in post method api and above code is not working. I'm getting nil response. But this url is working properly in postman and android studio too. What is the reason behind this issue?**

Comment: You need add your parameters in the request body i think, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484772/how-to-post-nested-json-by-swiftyjson-and-alamofire/44500753#44500753 maybe can help you

Comment: Yes i've added the parametersDictionary there

Comment: The code `(parametersDictionary as NSDictionary) as? Parameters` is probably giving you `nil`.

Comment: I've edited it to parametersDictionary only. Still not working. You can check this url in postman. Its fine in there. But when I use it in code it gives nil response

Comment: @Sptibo use GET instead of POST and must work

Comment: But I've to post form data in server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url only works when requesting using form with url encoded

[image]

Try to use this, as [documented](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) on GitHub

```
Alamofire.request("http://nanosoftech.com/store/user_check", method: .post, parameters: parametersDictionary , encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

If this encoding doesn't work, try `encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody`

Comment: @Sptibo Just noticed that you are sending an http call, not https one. You will need to do https only or your app will be rejected by app store. From the beginning of 2017, http calls are only allowed in a `UIWebView`

Comment: @Sptibo I just tried to send post request with `{"email" : "name@email.com", "password": "haha"}` and got nil respond

Comment: But i've been working with http urls in get methods and are working well. If I test this code with another http url and post some form data then that is working. But this url is giving me nil response.

Comment: @Sptibo Look at the screen shot I updated. Your url is indeed returning nil

Comment: You've send raw data. But I'd send form data. Is that same thing? Try sending form data and look at the response.

Comment: @Sptibo Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you @Fangming Ning. Yesterday I didn't marked your changes. URLEncoding.default is working.

Comment: I see the image now (from home), so it must have been something like that. Sorry for the false alarm! I'll delete my comments now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just write look Like bellow.. It is working for me

```
Alamofire.request("http://era.com.bd/UserSignInSV", method: .post,parameters:["uname":txtUserId.text!,"pass":txtPassword.text!]).responseJSON{(responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value != nil)){

            let jsonData = JSON(responseData.result.value)

        }
    }
```

Comment: it is working in live project running on. I think you should see the json response..Can you show me json response...

Comment: Check browser using get because browser do not response from post: http://nanosoftech.com/store/user_check?email=name@gmail.com&password=password

Comment: I've tested this url in postman, checked form-data and fill "email" and "password" in body and send it. Its working well in postman.

Comment: Hello dear, I have found json response my json response is from the code I have printed in xcode with same code. Is json is look like bellow. If still feel problem please share your code...:::jsonData : {
  "loginNodes" : [
    {
     
      "errorCode" : "1",
    
      "errorMessage" : "Unauthorized User ID. Sign In Denied."
    }
  ]
}